# jQuery validate call custom method if other field not empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate plugin and I have a custom method where the field I'm validating must be greater than another field.

The problem I face is when the other field is blank (not required), I get a validation message saying the value must be greater than ther other field which has no value.

I need to call my custom method only if the other field has a value or at leat pass validation on that part.

```
$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function (value, element, param) {
    var $otherElement = $(param);
    return parseInt(value, 10) > parseInt($otherElement.val(), 10);
});



rules: {
    other_field: {
        required: false,
        min: 0,
        number: true
    },
    my_field: {
        required: true,
        min: 1,
        number: true,
        greaterThan: "#other_field"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to call my custom method only if the other field has a value

So simply use a conditional to see if it's blank before you enforce the rule...

```
$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function (value, element, param) {
    var $otherElement = $(param);
    if ($otherElement != '') { // <- the other field not empty?
        return parseInt(value, 10) > parseInt($otherElement.val(), 10);
    };
    return true; // <- other field was empty, no error message
});
```

Adjust the logic as needed... maybe trim blank spaces, test for a zero, etc.